# update using (self?) joins

Tags: sql

I have a membership-table with userid as primary key.

I have another table (table A) containing two foreign keys to the membership-table (tableA.userid1 and tableA.userid2).

Now I want to update the emailadress inside the membership-table of userid2 with the emailadress of userid1.

How can I do that? Something like...

```
Update membership m2
set m2.email = m1.email
...???
```

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE m2
SET email=m1.email
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN membership m1 ON ta.UserID1=m1.UserID
INNER JOIN membership m2 ON ta.UserID2=m2.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 update A
     join membership as m1 on A.userid1 = m1.id
     join membership as m2 on A.userid2 = m2.id
 set m2.email = m1.email
```

where

```
create table membership (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  email varchar(100)
);

create table A (
  userId1 int,
  userId2 int,
  constraint foreign key (userId1) references membership (id),
  constraint foreign key (userId2) references membership (id)
);

insert into membership (email) values
  ("user1@stackoverflow.com"),
  ("user2@stackoverflow.com");

insert into A values (1, 2);
```

The update command sets the email of user 2 to that of user 1:

```
select * from membership;

id  email
1   user1@stackoverflow.com
2   user1@stackoverflow.com
```

Here is a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3105d/1/0)

Comment: Its working, although I think the one from Ghost is easier to read, because yours is starting with update A, and table A is not the one that is updated.

Comment: Second constraint should be userId2, but I can't edit the post

Comment: I agree, his is better.